# How many $4$-digit numbers of the form $1a2b$ are divisible by $3$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

How many $4$-digit numbers of the form $\overline{1a2b}$ are divisible by $3?$

Hello I am new here so I don’t really know how this works. I know that for something to be divisible by 3, you add the digits and see if they are divisible by $3$. So that means $3+a+b=6, 9, 12, 15, 18,$ or $21.$ I’m just confused about how to calculate the number of cases.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the downvote here. This new contributor has clearly shown that they have thought about the problem and has described where they got stuck. +1 for showing your thoughts so far, and welcome to math.stackexchange!

Comment: Observe that "$1a2b$" is divisible by $3$ iff "$ab$" is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving you a hint :-

You got $3 + a + b = 6,9,12,15,18$ or $21$, which implies that $a + b = 3,6,9,12,15$ or $18.$ Now do Case-Work and find all possible $a,b$ which can satisfy these . This may take a bit of work.

$($For e.g. when $a + b = 3$ we have $(a,b) = (0,3),(1,2)(2,1)(3,0))$

Note that you forgot  the case when $3 + a + b = 3$, in that case $(a,b)$ = $(0,0)$.

**Edit** :- Keep in mind that $a,b$ are $1$-digit numbers . Hence if $a + b = 12$ , $(a,b) = (1,11)$ is not a solution, but $(a,b) = (3,9)$ is a solution .

Comment: This is a nice answer. One suggestion: when you write "You got :- $3 + a + b$..." one might accidentally read that as $-3 + a + b$ instead of $3 + a + b$. I would remove the "-" for clarity.

Comment: That's actually true . As your suggestion I am removing it :) .

Comment: Oh ok thank you for the help!

Comment: But wouldn’t this result in a lot of cases? Because for 6 I wouldn’t it be (0,6), (1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1),(6,0) and wouldn’t there be even more for cases like 18?

Comment: It definitely would result a lot of cases , but it won't be that difficult to count all of those . Also note that for $18$, u only have $(9,9)$ as $a$ and $b$ are $1$-digit numbers

Comment: ohhh I see. I think I’ve solved it now!

Comment: I got 34 cases. If you have time could you check if that’s right?

Comment: Yeah , $34$ is the correct answer . Good Job !

Comment: Yay thank you so much!!! :D